# Why doesn't this javascript run on page load, only on refresh?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function problem(){
        var num1 = parseInt(Math.random()*11);
        var num2 = parseInt(Math.random()*11);  
        document.write("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2);
        var answer = num1 + num2;
        //document.write(answer);
        ans = prompt("Enter your answer??");
        if(ans == answer){
            alert("Good JOB!");
        }else{
            alert("Fail xD");
        }
    }
    problem();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I run this the prompt window doesn't pop up automatically, it comes up when it refresh, I want to appear right when i run the program.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use document.write as it will overwrite the page's content. Instead, create an element to hold the question (like a div) and refer to it like:

```
function problem() {
    var num1 = parseInt(Math.random() * 11);
    var num2 = parseInt(Math.random() * 11);
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "What is " + num1 + " + " + num2;
    var answer = num1 + num2;
    ans = prompt("Enter your answer??");
    if (ans == answer) {
        alert("Good JOB!");
    } else {
        alert("Fail xD");
    }
}
problem();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PM9ax/)**